# NearestPoint does not work with points very close to axis

Tags: teechart

I am using NearestPoint which reports the x/y values in a jlabel, but I have noticed that if I hover over a point that is on the edge of the chart [extremely close to any axis] that it is not detected by NearestPoint. Is there a way round this problem or how can I create space between the edge of the chart and the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way round this problem

This works fine for me here. Can you please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here? You can send it at http://www.steema.net/upload/

> or how can I create space between the edge of the chart and the
>   points?

You can use axis minimum and maximum offset, for example:

```
    tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setMinimumOffset(10);
    tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setMaximumOffset(10);
```

Comment: Thats just what I was looking for. Thanks.